# can't resolve module inside subdirectory typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The module `arrayGenerator.ts` lies inside a subfolder, it works fine for other modules(`Array.ts`) inside the parent folder. But when I add a new module `Sorting.ts`, it gives me can't resolve the error.
There is inconsistency regarding the compilation. no `Array.js` in dist but it was working.. path is like this. and below is my `tsconfig.json`. I tried some configurations like change "src" to `"src/**/*"`, but all don't work or the compiler turned down the changes.

```
dir
 - slices
  - dist 
  - Array.ts
  - Sorting.ts
  - bricks
    - arrayGenerator.ts

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding `"baseUrl": "src"` to compilerOptions?

Comment: yes I tried this but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The issue disappeared after I transferred code to a new template.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and it went away after re-saving the files that caused errors. The problem is very reproducible when moving or renaming files. Seems like Webpack is not updating its cache.